# Disable headers in sub-files when compiled stand-alone

Tags: fancyhdr, subfiles

I am writing a large report (using the `report` class), and hence have a "main" file alongside all the *parts* as separate TeX files. The `subfiles` package is used to import all of the *part* files into the "main" file.

Although this works perfectly fine when compiling from the "main" file, the headers (using `fancyhdr`) fail to render properly when compiling a *part* file stand-alone, due to the header definition relying upon undefined macros such as `\thepart`.

Is there a way to "detect" if a sub-file is being compiled stand-alone, and if so, specify something which would disable headers (such as `\pagestyle{empty}`) ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can test if `\thepart` is defined using `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and either `\ifdef{\thepart}{〈true code〉}{〈false code〉}` or `\ifcsdef{thepart}{〈true code〉}{〈false code〉}`.

Comment: @frougon Thank you for the warm welcome, and your suggestion worked great ! If you'd like to add that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it :)

Comment: Glad to see it helped. I added a few complements. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [etoolbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package makes it easy to test if a control sequence is defined; this can also be done “manually” with e-TeX primitives such as `\ifcsname`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

% We could of course factor out the “is” too, but let's favor clarity over
% trying to be smart.
\verb|\thepart|
\ifdef{\thepart}{is}{is not} defined.

\verb|\thechapter|
\ifdef{\thechapter}{is}{is not} defined.

\bigskip
% Alternatively:
\verb|\thepart|
\ifcsdef{thepart}{is}{is not} defined.

\verb|\thechapter|
\ifcsdef{thechapter}{is}{is not} defined.

\bigskip
% Using the underlying e-TeX primitive (requires a TeX engine with e-TeX
% extensions, but not the 'etoolbox' package):
\verb|\thepart|
\ifcsname thepart\endcsname
  is     % <--- space here
\else
  is not % <--- space here
\fi
defined.

% Terse version, for a change
\verb|\thechapter| is
\ifcsname thechapter\endcsname\else not \fi defined.

\bigskip
% Using TeX only (no e-TeX extension), we can test if a control sequence is
% either undefined or \let-equal to \relax:
\verb|\thepart| is
\expandafter\ifx\csname thepart\endcsname\relax
  either undefined or \verb|\let|-equal to \verb|\relax|.
\else
  defined.
\fi

\verb|\thechapter| is
\expandafter\ifx\csname thechapter\endcsname\relax
  either undefined or \verb|\let|-equal to \verb|\relax|.
\else
  defined.
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]