# How to avoid defining something inside of a macro that uses '\csname \endcsname'?

Tags: macros, errors

The following code gives no error and works fine:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\def\ThingyFred {This is the thingy named Fred}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Fred}
    \ThingyFred
\end{document}
```

And the following code gives the error

> `"Undefined control sequence. \ThingyJoe"`,

which is what I would expect and hope it would do:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\def\ThingyFred {This is the thingy named Fred}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Fred}
    \ThingyJoe
\end{document}
```

But for various reasons, I want (in the main body of the document) to refer to things like `\Thingy{Fred}`, not `\ThingyFred`. The following works fine:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\def\RawThingyFred {This is the thingy named Fred}

\def\Thingy#1 {\csname RawThingy#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Fred}
    \Thingy{Fred}
\end{document}
```

But, contrary to my naive expectations and hopes, the following code does *not* give an error (it instead treats `\Thingy{Joe}` as an empty variable):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\def\RawThingyFred {This is the thingy named Fred}

\def\Thingy#1 {\csname RawThingy#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Fred}
    \Thingy{Joe}
\end{document}
```

After investigating a little more, it seems to me that the problem is that when you do a `\Thingy{Joe}`, the `\def\Thingy#1 \csname RawThingy#1\endcsname` does not merely translate to `\RawThingyJoe`, but additionally *defines* `\RawThingyJoe`. For example, the following returns the error that I would hope:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\def\RawThingyFred {This is the thingy named Fred}

\def\Thingy#1 {\csname RawThingy#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Fred}
    \RawThingyJoe
    \Thingy{Joe}
\end{document}
```

But the following does not get an error:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\def\RawThingyFred {This is the thingy named Fred}

\def\Thingy#1 {\csname RawThingy#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Fred}
    \Thingy{Joe}
    \RawThingyJoe
\end{document}
```

So it seems like in the first case, it sees `\RawThingyJoe` and has no idea what that means, whereas in the second case it sees `\Thingy{Joe}`, decides that `\RawThingyJoe` therefore means an empty string, and *then* sees `\RawThingyJoe`, which it interprets as an empty string.

Is there a way to take the "define a macro that takes a parameter" route, but still get the error-checking that I had expected?

Comment: From `\csname...\endcsname` TeX builds a control sequence name; if this name corresponds to an undefined control sequence, TeX *defines* it as equivalent to `\relax`. Please, look for `\csname` in the site: this topic has been discussed several times.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that `\def\x#1 {...}` and `\def\x#1{...}` are very different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As egreg wrote, `\csname` ... `\endcsname` defines the control sequence token to be `\let`-equivalent to `\relax` if it isn't already defined (you can think of it as a side effect of `\csname`). With e-TeX extensions, you can use `\ifcsname` to test whether a control sequence is defined, without defining it (no side effect):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\RawThingyFred}{This is the thingy named Fred}

\newcommand*{\Thingy}[1]{%
  \ifcsname RawThingy#1\endcsname
    \csname RawThingy#1\endcsname
  \else
    \errmessage{\string\RawThingy#1 is undefined}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\Thingy{Fred}% okay
\Thingy{Joe}% prints \RawThingyJoe is undefined.

\end{document}
```

You can see other techniques for this kind of test [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499151/73317).

P.S.: I changed your `\def`s to `\newcommand*`, first because `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*` ensure you don't accidentally overwrite an existing macro, second because your parameter text had a probably unwanted space (for instance, after `#1` in `\def\Thingy#1 {...}`).